# Why I am unable to access the values of methods in a Beanclass?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans, usebean

```
<jsp:useBean id="bc" class="com.go.Credentials" scope="session"/>
<%
     out.println( bc.getUserid());
 %>
```

I want to access the methods in my bean class Credentials. When I am trying to do so, I am getting null. Why?

Comment: I suggest, use clear sentences, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is a quick checklist.

Answer (score 0):

you get id value with

```
<jsp:getProperty name="bc" property="id"/>
```

or If you want scriplets

```
<%  
int value=bc.getUserid();  
out.print("user ID is : "+value);  
%>
```